# htaccess remove index from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a subfolder for my website, however, it still appears as `www.domain.com/community/index.html`.
I would like to remove the `/index.html` part.

I currently have this in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect html pages to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```

I have a basic understanding of what this does, though, I am unsure on how to achieve this, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the correct/best solution, however, I've created another .htaccess file within the sub directory, and that seems to work perfectly fine.
But if anyone has any better/correct solutions I'd still be happy to hear them.